# How to add background color and font style to List Box?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clr

I have a list box that was created using Visual Studio's Toolbox. In it, I added a few items. Here is the code Visual Studio generated for me:

```
// positionListBox
            // 
            this->positionListBox->FormattingEnabled = true;
            this->positionListBox->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Object^  >(7) {
                L"Engineer", L"Architect", L"Librarian", L"Doctor", L"Programmer", L"Painter",
                    L"Soldier"
            });
            this->positionListBox->Location = System::Drawing::Point(6, 19);
            this->positionListBox->Name = L"positionListBox";
            this->positionListBox->Size = System::Drawing::Size(219, 173);
            this->positionListBox->TabIndex = 1;
            this->positionListBox->SelectedIndexChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Main::positionListBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Is it possible to change the background color and font style in here, or is it better for me to just programatically create this list box?

I only want a few specific words with a different background color and font. Everything else I add will just be a normal background color and font (if that makes any sense).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color and style by `DrawItem` event and `DrawString`  function.

Need to change the `properties` of the listbox in advance: `DrawMode -> OwnerDrawFixed`

Code :

```
private: System::Void listBox1_DrawItem(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::DrawItemEventArgs^ e) {
    Color bColor= e->BackColor;//bakcground
    Color fColor = Color::Black; //font color
    System::Drawing::Font^ font=e->Font ;//font = gcnew System::Drawing::Font(listBox1->Font,System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold);
    if (this->listBox1->Items->Count > 0 && this->listBox1->Items->Count > e->Index)
    {
        if (e->Index < 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (this->listBox1->Items[e->Index]->ToString()->Contains("color1")) 
        { 
            fColor = Color::Black; bColor = Color::Yellow;
            font = gcnew System::Drawing::Font(e->Font, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold);
        }
        if (this->listBox1->Items[e->Index]->ToString()->Contains("color2")) 
        { 
            fColor = Color::Red; bColor = Color::White; 
        }
    }
    e->Graphics->FillRectangle(gcnew  SolidBrush(bColor), e->Bounds);
    e->Graphics->DrawString(this->listBox1->Items[e->Index]->ToString(), font, gcnew SolidBrush(fColor), e->Bounds);
    e->DrawFocusRectangle();
    
}
```